# Page is dead after download link is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a few linkbuttons that each open the save dialog to let users save file to the local machine. But after any link is clicked the page is dead afterwards (nothing works) and page has to be refreshed.

So do I have to force refresh after download is complete or does it have to do something with postback?

```
{

        StringCollection strValuesToSearch = new StringCollection();

        strValuesToSearch.Add("findword");

        string stringToReplace;

        stringToReplace = TextBox1.Text;




        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/test.txt")))
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();





            foreach (string s in strValuesToSearch)
            {

                if (result.Contains(s))

                    result = result.Replace(s, stringToReplace);




                Response.Clear();
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=super.txt");
                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                Response.BinaryWrite(encoding.GetBytes(result));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

Comment: It depends on how these LinkButtons are actually working - how do they push the file down?

Comment: Include part of your code that handles this.

Comment: Post some of the code that fetches the files to be downloaded, not just the refresh code.

Comment: Full cold posted, specific word in text file is replaced by another word inputted in the textbox by user

Comment: This is server-side code, your problem is client-side (perhaps with faulty ajax). You need to provide the html+js that is sent to the browser.

Comment: mmnn perhaps if I can force refresh after download to circumvent further troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of client-side code, this is just a wild guess at what is causing the issue:

1. User clicks on a link button
2. JS initiates `get` or `post` ajax call to the server, sending some data
3. Server sends `content-disposition` header followed by the file data
4. ajax process expects some other header to say the action has completed and this header never arrives, so it waits endlessly locking the UI.